Cannot change frame for a UIView wrapped inside a SwiftUI View
I have a UIView wrapped around a SwiftUI View. I later change the UIView size but somehow it always get back to the original size.
I have SwiftUI View wrapping around an UIView like this. This is one approach. I tried multiple approach like KVO but none of them works.
struct SomeUIViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    let uiView: UIView
    @Binding var frame: CGRect

    func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> UIView {
        return uiView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Self.Context) {
        print("updateUIView \(uiView.frame.size) frame \(frame.size)")
        if CGSizeEqualToSize(frame.size, CGSize(width: 256, height: 144)) {
            uiView.frame = frame
            uiView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView: View {

    @StateObject var model : ViewModel = .init()
    let view: UIView

    var body: some View {
        SomeUIViewRepresentable(uiView: view, frame: $model.frame)
            .frame(width: model.frame.width, height: model.frame.height)
            .onChange(of: model.frame) { newFrame in
                // Ensure that SwiftUI is notified when the frame changes
                print("SwiftUI frame updated to: \(newFrame.size)")
            }
    }
}

extension SwiftUIView {

    final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var frame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}

extension SwiftUIView.ViewModel: FrameChangeDelegate {
    func viewFrameChanged(view: UIView) {
        self.frame = view.frame // When it reaches here, the UIView is already set to a new size.
        print("viewFrameChanged \(view.frame.size) frame \(frame.size)")
    }
}


func createView() -> any View {
    let swiftUIView =  SwiftUIView(view: view)
    delegate.viewModel = swiftUIView.model

    return swiftUIView
}


Why I change the frame but it always get back to the original one (200, 200)? The onChange is not called at all.
I change the UIView frame size to (256, 144). I noticed that the layoutSubviews is called with the new frame size, but then a bit later (almost immediately) the UIView layoutSubviews is called again with the original size. What makes UIView layoutSubviews gets called the second time? Its content doesn't change.

Note: I've already changed the UIView frame by calling this following method before the viewFrameChanged delegate method is called.
- (void) updateSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, newSize.width, newSize.height);
    [self setNeedsLayout];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}

Here's some logs:
layoutSubviews: {256, 144}
viewFrameChanged (256.0, 144.0) frame (256.0, 144.0)
layoutSubviews: {200, 200}

Somehow the updateUIView is not called after setting the new frame self.frame = view.frame.

For a basic explanation, see my answer.  It may also help if you try to explain exactly what you are trying to achieve. There's usually no need to change the frame of a UIView embedded in a SwiftUI view.

SwiftUI has its own layout system, which cannot be combined with that of UIKit. With SwiftUI, the parent view determines the size and placement of a child view.
This means, for example, that the frame property in UIViewRepresentable must not be changed, as you do in your code.
Apple is also very clear about this in the developer documentation:

SwiftUI fully controls the layout of the UIKit view’s center, bounds, frame, and transform properties. Don’t directly set these layout-related properties on the view managed by a UIViewRepresentable instance from your own code because that conflicts with SwiftUI and results in undefined behavior.

Also note that updateUIView is intended exclusively for reacting to state changes from SwiftUI and not for layout changes.
If you want to react to size changes of a SwiftUI view, you must either do this with the help of a GeometryReader or use your own Layout implementation.
See here and here how to implement your own layouts and here how to use a GeometryReader.
